# Set maxFeePerGas and maxPriorityFeePerGas dynamically in ethers js

Tags: gas, ethers.js, gas-price, polygon

I want to set the value of maxPriorityFeePerGas and maxFeePerGas these two parameters when sending a transaction, say 10 gwei greater than the response from getFeeData() function.

```
/* provider.getFeeData
gasPrice: BigNumber {_hex: '0x59682f89', _isBigNumber: true}
maxFeePerGas: BigNumber {_hex: '0x59683012', _isBigNumber: true}
maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber {_hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true}
*/
```

Deoded as something like, not exact conversion: (not sure if this really means this)

```
/* provider.getFeeData
    gasPrice: 4
    maxFeePerGas: 12
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: 14
    */
```

Now I am trying to set these values while sending trasaction but they are not applying on the metamask. I might be completely wrong please help.

```
    writeContract.methodName(arg1,arg2,{
//try 1
              maxFeePerGas: feeData.maxFeePerGas.add(BigNumber.from('10'))._hex,
              maxPriorityFeePerGas: feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas.add(BigNumber.from('10'))._hex,

//try 2
              maxFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits('50','gwei'),
              maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits('40','gwei'),

/try 3
              maxFeePerGas: feeData.maxFeePerGas,
              maxPriorityFeePerGas: feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas,});
```

None of the above methods worked and Metamask automatically pulls the values from the network.